# Why flutter in debug mode shows the permission status "denied" where its actually "permanentlyDenied"?

Tags: flutter, permissions, imagepicker

I'm really bit confused, in order to test my app I denied the permission to photos and camera however App doesn't ask again for permission when using image picker package, And instead enable me to upload the images freely! ? any idea about app behavior in debug mode? and why permission status not displayed correctly, any idea what is the proper steps to denied it permanently ?

```
_getFromGallery() async {
    if (await Permission.photos.request().isGranted) {
      PickedFile? image = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {

        /// For storing image in local memory:
        // final File file = File(image.path);
        // final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        // final imagepath = directory.path;
        // final String fileName = path.basename(image.path);
        // File newImage = await file.copy('$imagepath/$fileName');

        setState(() {
          _imagelocal = File(image.path);
          _uploadimage();
        });
      }
    }
    else if (await Permission.photos.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
        openAppSettings();
        PickedFile? image = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery);

        if (image != null) {


          /// For storing image in local memory:
          // final File file = File(image.path);
          // final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          // final imagepath = directory.path;
          // final String fileName = path.basename(image.path);
          // File newImage = await file.copy('$imagepath/$fileName');

          setState(() {
            _imagelocal = File(image.path);
            _uploadimage();
          });
        }
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have just check one permission for photos, Try check for all permission camera, storage, photo

Example:

```
void _checkPermission(BuildContext context) async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statues = await [
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.photos
    ].request();
    PermissionStatus? statusCamera = statues[Permission.camera];
    PermissionStatus? statusStorage = statues[Permission.storage];
    PermissionStatus? statusPhotos = statues[Permission.photos];
    bool isGranted = statusCamera == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        statusStorage == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.granted;
    if (isGranted) {
      _openPickImage(context);
    }
    bool isPermanentlyDenied =
        statusCamera == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied ||
            statusStorage == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied ||
            statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied;
    if (isPermanentlyDenied) {
      _showSettingsDialog();
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, issue has been solved, yes we need to check storage and photos as well, i noticed that android asks for storage permission while IOS asks for photo, i will answer my question with updated code

Answer (score 0):

After long time of investigation I noticed the following:

1- As mentioned in the subject `PermissionStatus`returns always **denied** even though its actual status is **permanentlyDenied**, No idea why?

2- Photo permission is not available at least on my testing android device, instead it has storage permission only, where IOS has photo and doesn't have Storage permission..so in order to test the permission for photos/storage in both android and IOS in one statement, You need to test the permission for both of them, photo permission on android always true, no idea if IOS behaves the same and returns true for permission storage?

Updated Code:

```
Future<void> _showMyDialogStorage() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.permissionToStorage),
          content: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.applicationneedsThispermissiontoworkproperly),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => {
                openAppSettings(),
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        settings: const RouteSettings(
                          name: "/PostLoad",),
                        builder: (
                            BuildContext context) =>
                            PostLoad(mobile_number: widget.mobile_number,))),
              },
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ok),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      settings: const RouteSettings(
                        name: "/PsotLoad",),
                      builder: (
                          BuildContext context) =>
                          PostLoad())),
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cancel),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Get image from gallery and store it locally
  Future<void> _getFromGallery() async {
    var status_storage = await Permission.storage.status;
    var status_photo = await Permission.photos.status;

    if (status_storage == PermissionStatus.granted && status_photo == PermissionStatus.granted) {

      PickedFile? image = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {

        /// For storing image in local memory:
        // final File file = File(image.path);
        // final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        // final imagepath = directory.path;
        // final String fileName = path.basename(image.path);
        // File newImage = await file.copy('$imagepath/$fileName');

        setState(() {
          _imagelocal = File(image.path);
          _uploadimage();
        });
      }
    }

    else if (status_storage == PermissionStatus.denied || status_photo == PermissionStatus.denied) {

      // Permission.storage.request();
      _showMyDialogStorage();
    }

    else if (status_storage == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied || status_photo == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {

      _showMyDialogStorage();

      }

  }
```

Comment: which package are you using ? because i didn't find a way to access the Permission in the image_picker !

Comment: @hassanyassin I use https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler